# How to efficiently deserialize only given range of objects from a big serialized file

Tags: java, deserialization

I have a big serialized object file containing more the 200K objects, which I want to deserialize 500 objects at a time, for a given range of `fromIndex` and `toIndex`.

The below code works fine, however, it takes long to iterate through the chuck, and store only the ones which fall within the given range: `if( i >= fromIndex && i < toIndex )`:

```
public void deserializeFile( int fromIndex, int toIndex ) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
{
    m_objects_list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
    try 
    {
        BufferedInputStream bufferedStream = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream("myObjects.ser") );
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream( bufferedStream );

        int i=0;
        int count=0;
        MyObject obj = new MyObject();
        while (true) 
        {               
            Object object = inputStream.readObject();                   

            if( i >= fromIndex && i<toIndex )
            {
                obj = (MyObject) object;                    
                m_objects_list.add(obj);
                count++;
            }
            i++;
            if( count == toIndex - fromIndex )
            {
                inputStream.close();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (EOFException EOF) 
    {
        inputStream.close();
        return;
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException c) 
    {
        System.out.println("Class not found");
        c.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }       
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to directly read the object at the given index and iterate from there, instead of always starting to read from the first object?

Comment: Could you please share some info on how MyObject looks like? What are the fields in side? How much nesting is there? Do they share references to anything?

Comment: You can't. Object streams can contain state that is referenced later on. They are not random access files.

Comment: @Ivan, MyObject is a simple Pojo kind of class with bunch of String, Double, Date fields.  It has nested objects to another simple Pojo kind of objects.  But there is no sharing of references.

Comment: There is sharing of references to classes, if nothing else. That means that the serialization of any given object is variable length, which is what makes your requirement impossible.

Comment: @EJP, Thanks for clarification.  Further, is there a way to know the size of object read by >Object object = inputStream.readObject(); 
So that I may skip the same in subsequent call via intputSteam.skip(sizeInBytesToSkip);

Comment: Sigh. **YOU CANNOT DO THIS.**  There is state in the file that you cannot skip. I have already said all this.

Comment: I wish there were a better way.  I am sure technology would evolve today or tomorrow.  There wasn't a need to down vote on the question itself.  Thanks to all for your inputs.

Answer (score -1):

You may give a try with skipping bytes in input stream like the following

```
public void deserializeFile( int fromIndex, int toIndex ) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
{
    m_objects_list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
    try 
    {
        BufferedInputStream bufferedStream = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream("myObjects.ser") );
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream( bufferedStream );

        intputSteam.skip(fromIndex);

        int i=0;
        int count=0;
        MyObject obj = new MyObject();
        while (true) 
        {               
            Object object = inputStream.readObject();                   

            if( i >= fromIndex && i<toIndex )
            {
                obj = (MyObject) object;                    
                m_objects_list.add(obj);
                count++;
            }
            i++;
            if( count == toIndex - fromIndex )
            {
                inputStream.close();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (EOFException EOF) 
    {
        inputStream.close();
        return;
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException c) 
    {
        System.out.println("Class not found");
        c.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }       
}
```

inputstream.skip skips the number of bytes in the underlying stream and reads from the `fromIndex` position so that you can deserialize the rest of the input stream from where you need.

Comment: It won't. You can't know hiow many bytes to slip, and you may skip over an object that is referenced later in the stream as a handle.

Comment: @Rajasuba Subramanian, This does not work as correctly pointed out by EJP, but this is exactly what I am looking for, a similar mechanism which would skip over the given number of objects before starting to read from inputStream.